Change pane size with iterm2 and apple script
I'm trying to operate on iTerm2 like tmux, so I started from itermocil script. I need a two small pane on the top, one large horizontal pane in the bottom, so I first added this layout

        elif layout == 'main-horizontal-flipped':

            self.applescript.append(create_pane(1, num_panes, "horizontal"))
            for p in range(2, num_panes):
                self.applescript.append(create_pane(p-1, p, "vertical"))

This worked, but the pane height are the same. How can I adjust the height of the bottom pane and make it 2/3 of the full height of iterm2?
It looks like everything is done with applescript, but I couldn't find reference in iterm2's website.
        def create_pane(parent, child, split="vertical"):

            return (''' tell pane_{pp}
                            set pane_{cp} to (split {o}ly with same profile)
                        end tell
                    '''.format(pp=parent, cp=child, o=split))

Does anyone know how to do that?
